# How is continued fraction of numbers like pi are calculated

Tags: number-theory, pi, transcendental-numbers

I know how to find the continued fraction of rational numbers, and irrational numbers which square root of rational number. But how to find continued fraction of numbers like pi, e etc.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: So what do you mean exactly? It's not that difficult to figure out the first few terms of a continued fraction for $\pi$. You start with a 
$$
3
$$
After that, we know that $\frac{1}{3-\pi} \approx 7.0625$, so the next term is
$$
3 + \frac{1}{7}
$$
and continue from that ...

Comment: I meant that how do we know the pattern would continue. Let's take the example of e it has continued fraction of 1,2,1,1,4,1,1,8... So how do we know the pattern continues

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Calculating_continued_fraction_representations but this method needs high precision beyond the first few terms

Comment: The simple continued fraction of $\pi$ is conjectured to be completely patternless, same is conjectured for numbers like $\sqrt[3]{2}$. $e$ is one of the expections concerning this. The only thing, we can however rule out is a peridodical sequence because this gives a real root of a quadratic function with integer coefficients.